# how to upload multiple images in canvas and resize

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

how to upload multiple images in canvas has a separate layer and resize all the layer also.
in this code was upload only one image not able to resize. but in need to upload multiple images and resize all the images which one in the canvas

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
        imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('Layer_1');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function handleImage(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
    }

}); 




<label>Image File:</label><br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>

<div id="holder">
    <canvas id="Layer_1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You need answer for this question right now?

Answer (score 0):

In your html input element specify `multiple` so the user can select multiple files.

Then in your handleImage you can loop through multiple e.target.files instead of just one [0].

As for resizing, you can use the extended version of drawImage:

```
// resize the original image as desired and draw it at [x,y]

ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,x,y,desiredWidth,desiredHeight);
```